# Does the Hunter's Mark spell work with pebbles that have the Magic Stone spell cast on them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *Magic Stone* spell creates pebbles that can be used to make a ranged spell attack by hurling or firing from a sling.  *Hunter's Mark* requires a 'weapon attack' to take effect.

Jeremy Crawford has ruled in a variety of (to me conflicting) ways on the subject of Magic Stone:

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/940654827683631110

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/652548438966403072

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/752595441477312512

It seems explicitly clear that Sneak Attack is okay when using a sling (but not when hurled).  But is *Hunter's Mark* also okay when using a sling?

Comment: Note that sneak attack specifies "Attack", which I believe would include any sort of attack such as weapon, spell, or ranged, will hunter's mark specifies "Weapon Attack"

Comment: The relevant bit is that Sneak Attack requires a finesse or _ranged weapon_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, *magic stone* is a spell attack, not a weapon attack.

The description of [*hunter’s mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) says:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a **weapon attack**

The description of the [*magic stone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone) says:

> You or someone else can make a ranged **spell attack** with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling.

Since *magic stone* is not a weapon attack, but is instead a spell attack, it does not work with *hunter’s mark*.

Comment: How does this relate to the use of the word 'can' and the fact that sling attacks are normally weapon attacks? Can you choose not to use the ranged spell attack option and just hurl the rock the old fashioned way?

Comment: @SeriousBri You chuck it like a normal rock and it will do normal rock damage.

Comment: @SeriousBri It’s a rock in a sling, which usually works, and there is nothing that says you can’t?

Comment: "you can make a spell attack" means you have a choice, and don't have to make a spell attack, but that could be because you have the option of not using it at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130622/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-armb).

Comment: For what it is worth I was just kinda playing devil's advocate to see if there was a good reason that 'can' doesn't change the allowable options. Having seen the chat I think I agree (I would rule differently because magic stone needs all the help it can get, but that is another matter), but I also think some of that reasoning would improve this answer, otherwise I am going to read this in a year after the comments have gone and immediately wonder the exact same question about the word 'can'. But maybe I am alone in those thoughts, in which case don't waste effort just to appease me.

Comment: How does this differ from Sneak Attack, though:  "Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an Attack if you have advantage on the Attack roll. The Attack must use a Finesse or a _ranged weapon_."  The second link is Crawford explicitly stating that Sneak Attack works with Magic Stones when slung.

Comment: To answer my own comment, slinging Magic Stones uses a _ranged weapon_, but it still makes a ranged _spell_ attack, not a _weapon_ attack.

Comment: @SeriousBri - 'Can' gives you the two options for using Magic Stones:  hurl them or sling them.  I'm not sure why you're reading it as giving you an option to not make a ranged spell attack?  You (or someone else) don't have to use the Magic Stones for anything, but you _can_, if you want, and here's how.